Find time difference between a row and a previous row that has a given value
I am trying to calculate the time difference between every row that is NaN in execution_size and the previous row where it wasn't NaN.

For example, row 3 and 4 would calculate the time difference with row 2
Row 6 would calculate the time difference with row 5,
Row 8,9,10 would calculate the time difference with row 7

I can't think of a native way of doing this using .diff() in Pandas.
                        timestamp  execution_size
1   2023-09-11 07:13:41.274903340             NaN
2   2023-09-11 07:13:41.274913154             6.0
3   2023-09-11 07:13:41.274918255             NaN
4   2023-09-11 07:13:41.274953408             NaN
5   2023-09-11 07:13:41.274957424             6.0
6   2023-09-11 07:13:41.274962953             NaN
7   2023-09-11 07:13:41.275002981             9.0
8   2023-09-11 07:13:41.275027960             NaN
9   2023-09-11 07:13:41.277197047             NaN
10  2023-09-11 07:13:41.277207543             NaN


Images of data/code are not acceptable, please provide a [mre] (as text)

Also, please explain what you want to do with the result?  Add a column to the data set or other?

Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples for best practices related to Pandas questions.

IIUC you could use compute a mask with isna, then ffill the valid timestamps and use them to perform a subtraction:
# ensure datetime
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# identify NaNs
m = df['execution_size'].isna()

# compute difference from previous non-NaN
df.loc[m, 'diff'] = df['timestamp'].sub(df['timestamp'].mask(m).ffill())

Output:
                       timestamp  execution_size                      diff
1  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274903340             NaN                       NaT
2  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274913154             6.0                       NaT
3  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274918255             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.000005101
4  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274953408             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.000040254
5  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274957424             6.0                       NaT
6  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274962953             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.000005529
7  2023-09-11 07:13:41.275002981             9.0                       NaT
8  2023-09-11 07:13:41.275027960             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.000024979
9  2023-09-11 07:13:41.277197047             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.002194066
10 2023-09-11 07:13:41.277207543             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.002204562

Intermediates:
                       timestamp  execution_size                      diff      m                          mask                         ffill                       sub
1  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274903340             NaN                       NaT   True                           NaT                           NaT                       NaT
2  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274913154             6.0                       NaT  False 2023-09-11 07:13:41.274913154 2023-09-11 07:13:41.274913154           0 days 00:00:00
3  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274918255             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.000005101   True                           NaT 2023-09-11 07:13:41.274913154 0 days 00:00:00.000005101
4  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274953408             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.000040254   True                           NaT 2023-09-11 07:13:41.274913154 0 days 00:00:00.000040254
5  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274957424             6.0                       NaT  False 2023-09-11 07:13:41.274957424 2023-09-11 07:13:41.274957424           0 days 00:00:00
6  2023-09-11 07:13:41.274962953             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.000005529   True                           NaT 2023-09-11 07:13:41.274957424 0 days 00:00:00.000005529
7  2023-09-11 07:13:41.275002981             9.0                       NaT  False 2023-09-11 07:13:41.275002981 2023-09-11 07:13:41.275002981           0 days 00:00:00
8  2023-09-11 07:13:41.275027960             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.000024979   True                           NaT 2023-09-11 07:13:41.275002981 0 days 00:00:00.000024979
9  2023-09-11 07:13:41.277197047             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.002194066   True                           NaT 2023-09-11 07:13:41.275002981 0 days 00:00:00.002194066
10 2023-09-11 07:13:41.277207543             NaN 0 days 00:00:00.002204562   True                           NaT 2023-09-11 07:13:41.275002981 0 days 00:00:00.002204562


THanks for this, it's what I was looking for, and thx for the edit on my post.

Code
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
cond = df['execution_size'].notna()
out = df['timestamp'] - df.groupby(cond.cumsum())['timestamp'].transform('first')

